# Deallocating memory of this particular 2d array

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I'm currently using a particular API such that I must use raw pointers, however given the particular arrangement of the pointers I'm not sure how to best go about clearing the memory and avoiding any undefined behaviour in doing so.

```
double *data1 = new double[rows*columns];
double **data2 = new double*[rows];
data2[0] = data1;  // Point to first row

for (int i = 1; i < columns; i++) {
    data2[i] = data2[i - 1] + rows;
}
```

I've attempted something like below, but I don't think it's right.

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    delete [] data2[i];
}
delete [] data2;
delete [] data1;
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead?

Comment: If you have 2 `new`s, you should have 2 `delete`s. Your example has `rows + 2` deletes. Basically, count the number of news and deletes that you have, and they should end up being equal.

Comment: Does the order of the deletion make any difference here?

Comment: No, it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

## Who owns What?

Is the question which will dictate how you delete objects.

What I think you're doing is creating one large array to hold a two-dimensional array of data, and then creating another array to hold pointers to the beginning of each row.

So that's two news and therefore two deletes.

It might be easier to visualise like this:

```
struct matrix_view
{
    int rows, columns;

    // this pointer owns a block of doubles
    double* entire_buffer = nullptr;

    // this pointer owns a block of pointers, but not the memory
    // they point to
    double** row_pointers = nullptr;
};

matrix_view create_matrix(int rows, int columns)
{
    auto result = matrix_view{ rows, columns, nullptr, nullptr };

    auto size = rows * columns;
    result.entire_buffer = new double [size];
    result.row_pointers = new double* [rows];
    auto first = result.entire_buffer;
    auto last = first + size;
    auto dest = result.row_pointers;
    while (first != last) {
        *dest++ = first;
        first += columns;
    }
    return result;
}

void destroy_matrix(matrix_view m)
{
    // always destroy in reverse order

    delete [] m.row_pointers;
    delete [] m.entire_buffer;
}
```